# When not logged in, the "faq" link on top is falling down

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Happens in Chrome 26.0.1410.43 screen size 1400x1050 (not really relevant, design is centered on width of 980px) and Windows 7.

> [image]

When logged in it appears fine.

Comment: Can you provide the browser + version, screen size, etc to help debug this issue?

Comment: this also happens on skeptics

Comment: @MarcoCeppi added some more details, thanks.

Comment: @Sklivvz Is this limited to just *some* sites? Or does it occur on all sites accessed by that browser/platform combination?

Comment: @EliahKagan it's on a few lucky sites and my hunch is that it depends on the font.

Comment: @Sklivvz question is should this be migrated to the main meta site since it's affecting more than one site? Not sure of that myself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it would be best so people from other sites can also comment on this.

Comment: definitely a bug. It's obvious that user not logged in is a newcomer who needs to be educated. For this guy, "faq" link apparently should not just fall down once, but jump randomly over different parts of the screen, blinking like crazy and doing many more weird things to bring user attention and make them wish to click it. I think this should be called "faq hunt" game and user who wins it (who manages to click), should get +5 reputation as a reward

Comment: @gnat think you just gave the devs here a very good idea for next April fools!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a white space issue.

It's fixed and will be rolled out in the next deployment.